# Failed to retrieve attachments from slack channel using Java

Tags: java, slack, slack-api

Let's say there is an attachment in the slack channel . And that attachment has some unique identifier So if I type the identifier i should get the attachment as response in the channel.

Example: if i type 45 and its related to an xml file attached in the slack channel, then it should reply with the uploaded attachment in the conversation.

I tried using GET method for `https://slack.com/api/channels.history?&channel=<>&count=1&pretty=1&inclusive=true&token=<>` and I obtained the history of the conversation in the channel.

Don't know how timestamp and unfurl can help in achieving this.

Comment: My apologizes, but I am not sure I understand what your issue is. Can you please rephrase? In general the response from channels.history will contain a list of all message (including their attachments) for that channel and the timestamp is the ID of a message.

Answer (score 0):

The API method [`channels.history`](https://api.slack.com/methods/channels.history) returns a list of messages from a specific channel as a big JSON array. It will only return the 100 latest by default and you have to use [paging](https://api.slack.com/methods/channels.history#navigating_through_collections_of_messages) if your channel contains more messages.

Messages are referenced by timestamp (`ts`). Attachments are elements of its message and references by ID (`id`), which represents the order their are shown on Slack.

So to access a specific attachment you first need to find the correct message by its timestamp and then you can find the attachment by its ID.

If you know the timestamp of the message you are interested in you can include `latest=timestam`p and `oldest=timestamp` in your API call to receive only that message.

If you do not know the timestamp of the message you will have to retrieve all messages within a reasonable timeframe and then detect your message based on some other criteria.

Btw. I would consider switching to [conversations.history](https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.history), which is the new and recommend API method for retrieving messages from all type of channels.

Comment: Thanks @Erik , could you please help me to find out how the mentioning actually works in this case. I am having a bot, when an id  regarding the attachment added in that slack channel is being mentioned in the channel, the bot should return the attachment from archieves . If you can provide the java code to do this, it will be really helpful.

Comment: I am still not sure how your app is supposed to work. Are you using slash commands? Or are you talking to a bot? How do you specify which message you are addressing with regards to the attachment? Please add this info to your question, so that people can better understand the context. Also please add your current best code to your question. Note that Stack Overflow is not a coding service, so please do not ask people to write the code for you.

Comment: ,I understood that my question seemed to be confusing. I am a beginner, really sorry. Thanks for taking effort. I will put the question in a better way